# Two databases synced backup

Tags: linux, backup, bash, mysql

I got a system that need two databases to work. I need a script to backup both databases at given point of time. I need databases to be in sync, so I need to be sure that backup does not allow changes in one of databases when the other is being backed up.

```
mysqldump db1 db2 > db1_db2.sql
```

Is the above code appropriate for this. Will it lock both databases for the time of backup, so I will get synced backup? What is the proper way to achieve this ? How would I do this, but with separated file for each database ?

EDIT:

Most of tables use InnoDB engine, but there are few less important tables that use archive engine.

Comment: What are the underlying tables?  You need to handle myisam, and innodb differently.  You probably need `--single-transaction`, or `--lock-all-tables` though.  I hope you are using innodb if you really care about changes being atomic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is the following

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --databases db1 db2 > db1_db2.sql
```

The option [--single-transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) creates a point-in-time window for all the data in the dump. The only restriction is that you do not execute any DDL

- `ALTER TABLE`
- `CREATE TABLE`
- `DROP TABLE`
- `RENAME TABLE`
- `TRUNCATE TABLE`
- Please see [my DBA StackExchange post `row locking within ACID transaction innodb`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58712/877) to see all the statement that can intermittently harm transactions.

As long as you do not execute any of these for the duration of the mysqldump, db1 and db2 will be a perfect snapshot from the moment the mysqldump starts.

Your non-InnoDB tables should be just fine, provided you do nothing to them: no DDL, no INSERTs, no UPDATEs, no DELETEs.

## UPDATE 2014-06-26 19:43 EDT

You asked

> Are single-transaction and lock-all-tables mutually exclusive? Is one of them implied\default?

Right from the MySQL Documentation on [**--single-transaction**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction)

> The --single-transaction option and the --lock-tables option are mutually exclusive because LOCK TABLES causes any pending transactions to be committed implicitly.

Yes, they are mutually exclusive.

Right from the MySQL Documentation on [**--lock-all-tables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-all-tables)

> Lock all tables across all databases. This is achieved by acquiring a global read lock for the duration of the whole dump. This option automatically turns off --single-transaction and --lock-tables.

Thus, `lock-all-tables` will disable `--single-transaction`

CAVEAT : Keep in mind that `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;` and all other heavy-handed (all-or-nothing) locking mechanisms will not completely stop InnoDB from doing writes to the system tablespace. [**I wrote about before in the DBA StackExchange**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29498/how-to-run-a-cold-backup-with-linux-tar-without-shutting-down-mysql-slave/29541#29541).

Here is a map of InnoDB for you to visual the other moving parts of InnoDB:

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Please read [How FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK works with Innodb Tables (MySQL Performance Blog)](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/23/how-flush-tables-with-read-lock-works-with-innodb-tables/) about other ill effects of locking all tables against InnoDB.

Comment: Are single-transaction and lock-all-tables mutually exclusive? Is one of them implied\default?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this URL for an overview of MySQL backups.

http://www.iheavy.com/2012/08/09/5-things-you-overlooked-with-mysql-dumps/

You need to add the following argument to lock both db's.

--lock-all-tables, -x

"Lock all tables across all databases. This is achieved by acquiring a global read lock for the duration of the whole dump".

Your command should be as shown below.

mysqldump -x --databases db1 db2

You could also consider replicating your MySQL databases to a slave server and to backup from the slave.

Comment: tnx. Is it also possible to do the same but split backup into separate files for each db ?

Comment: It is possible with scripting. Either by putting the db's in read only mode and then backing them up individually and then putting them back to read-write or by extracting the backup for a database from the mysqldump output.